# Use Cookies in PHP soap calls

Tags: php, cookies, soap

I need to use cookies in my PHP calls, currently i am using the below request:

```
$publish_Data ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <publishData xmlns="http://www.birst.com/">
      <token>'.$login_token.'</token>
      <spaceID>'.$space_id.'</spaceID>
      <date>'.$date.'</date>
    </publishData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';


$location_URL = "https://app2104.bws.birst.com/CommandWebService.asmx?wsdl";
$action_URL = "http://www.birst.com/publishData";


$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
'location' => $location_URL,
'uri'      => "",
'trace'    => 1,
));


try{
$publish_data_response = $client->__doRequest($publish_Data,$location_URL,$action_URL,1);
//Get response from here
//print_r($publish_data_response);
}catch (SoapFault $exception){
var_dump(get_class($exception));
var_dump($exception);
}
```

I need somehow to enable and use cookies in order in next calls that will follow.
i tried using

```
sessions_start()
```

but it didn't help - In Java, something called session_maintain_property is used which allows for the program to use cookies, how do i do the same in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved.
the issue was with the SoapClient, when i was sending a request i created a new SoapClient for every call and that gave me a different cookies per each call - kind of a different session.

basically you need to define the soap call only once:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
'location' => $location_URL,
'uri'      => "",
'trace'    => 1,
));
```

and use the same client for the rest of the calls.